# Error messages not showing upon validating form

Tags: java, spring-boot

So i have to make this app where you have a list of birdspecies and you can add new ones to the list. This form needs to have some validation but for some reason the error messages aren't showing up. Also, when you enter all the input correctly, everything works perfect but when you enter wrong input, it should just show the same page again, but it returns a whitelabel error instead.

here is my modelclass with the validation:

```
public class BirdSpecie {
@NotEmpty(message="This input may not be empty")
private String name;
@NotNull(message="This input may not be empty")
@DecimalMin(value="1250", message="The earliest year of discovery allowed is 1250")
private Integer yearOfDiscovery;

@NotEmpty(message="This input may not be empty")
@Pattern(regexp= "^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{3}$", message="Code should start with one or more capital letters [A-Z] followed by 3 digits")
private String code;
```

Here is my controller method:

```
@PostMapping(value="/{locationName}/addBirdSpecie")
public String onSubmit (
        @PathVariable("locationName")String locationName,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("spottedBirdSpecie") BirdSpecie birdSpecie,
        Model model, BindingResult result)
{
    model.addAttribute("spottedBirdSpecie", birdSpecie);
    BirdSpotLocation birdSpotLocation = spottedBirdService.findByName(locationName).get();
    yearValidation.validate(birdSpecie,result);
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addSpecie";
    }else {
    birdSpotLocation.increaseBirdSpot(birdSpecie);
    model.addAttribute("location", birdSpotLocation);
    return "birdsList";
    }
    
}
```

and here is my jsp file:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib prefix = "form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<spring:url value="/css/style.css" var="urlCss"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${urlCss}" type="text/css" />
<title>Create a new bird Specie</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Create new bird specie:  </h1>
<form:form method="post" action="addBirdSpecie" modelAttribute="spottedBirdSpecie">
<spring:url value="/birdspotting/" var="showLocation" />
<div>
<p>
Specie: <form:input path="name" size="25"/><br>
<form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/>
</p>
<p>
Year of discovery: <form:input path="yearOfDiscovery" size="25"/><br>
<form:errors path="yearOfDiscovery" cssClass="error"/>
</p>
<p>
Books of birds code: <form:input path="code" size="25"/><br>
<form:errors path="code" cssClass="error"/>
</p>

<input type="submit" value="Spot new bird"/> 
</div>

</form:form>


</body>
</html>
```

the error messages are showing correctly in my console, but they won't show up on the website.